# How to install dependencies for unity 8 music-app an terminal-app?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, ppa, music

I used vthompsom ppa to install unity 8 apps in my Ubuntu 16.04.

I could get file manager app, calculator app and weather app working. Media hub app installed but is not available in the dash. Music app could not install due to gstreamer.10-fluendo-mp3 dependency which will not be installed while terminal app installation broke my package. What do I do to get them installed and working. My system is up to date.